# Collection of Quadratic Forms of class number less than 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, class-field-theory

I am looking for a list/collection of *quadratic (or cubic, quartic) forms* of class number $k$ where $1 < k \leq 4$, possibly,  with equivalence class given explicitly (if exists in the literature).

Is there any book or research paper or survey paper listing/describing such forms?  Where can I find such forms? Thanks.

Comment: Recommend Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. Class number one (positive forms) was a gigantic research result, see Baker-Heegner-Stark. Class number two follows from the full list of Idoneal numbers. I remember three being published, I can look it up when I get home. Four must have 2 or 4 genera, so that will also be known.

Comment: 3    http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-246/S0025-5718-03-01517-5/

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html

Comment: http://www.numbertheory.org/classnos/